# Cannot call value of non-function 'module<F1>'

Tags: ios, module, frameworks, swift3

I created a Swift framework, just a simple test.

The Swift file (F1.swift) code:

```
public class F1{

    public init(){
        print("inited")
    }

    public func call(){
        print("called")
    }

}
```

Then, I built the framework and I imported it into another project.

I tried to use it this way:

```
import F1
```

in the `viewDidLoad` of a `UIViewController`:

```
var c = F1()
c.call()
```

The F1.framework has been dragged under:

- *General > Embedded Binaries*
- *General > Linked Frameworks and Binaries*

and I can also see it under:

- *Build Phases > Link Library With Binaries*
- *Build Phases > Embed frameworks*

The XCode "reaction": no issues with the `import` statement.

I receive an error exactly where the class is instantiated:

**Cannot call value of non-function 'module...'**

Am I missing something?

[update] Based on some online resources and some other test, I'm supposing the problem lies in *Build settings*: eg. *Build Active Architecture Only* could be involved, but it would be interesting to understand how and why.

Find minimal sample Xcode project [here](http://%20dropbox.com/s/foz3qa676damqhi/F2.zip?dl=0).

Comment: @shallowThought It takes less time for you to build a new blank project (New > Cocoa Touch Framework >...), I haven't done anything special

Comment: @shallowThought Nobody asked you to do it   :-)

Comment: @shallowThought I tried many times, with many different projects, it doesn't work. My version is Version 8.1 (8B62). Moreover, the process is quite simple, I really don't understand what can be wrong

Comment: @shallowThought here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/foz3qa676damqhi/F2.zip?dl=0 (there are small changes)

Comment: @shallowThought The project is a giant project and it is not my property, so I can't post it. But I can eventually create a blank project and import the module just for testing purposes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128814/discussion-between-shallowthought-and-ian-bell).

Comment: Sorry, I can't now. Anyway, I created a blank project: no success, it doesn't work. Don't worry, I can live without Swift modules   :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using your posted code gives the expected results here:

```
inited
called
```

Comment: I don't agree: the root of the problem probably lies in a mix of the two and something is related to build settings. The fact that it works on your end has no particular meaning: you could have the right settings "by chance".

Comment: I did use your (framework) project, without changing any settings. The only difference can be in the client project imo. To figure this out for you, please post a workspace project containing framework, a minimal sample client and showing the issue.

Comment: I must repeat myself: I *SIMPLY* create a blank project (single view), I import my framework and it doesn't work. It doesn't work in any case, in a giant project I'm working on and in ANY new project. It's completely useless I post the single view application template! I changed no setting, just like you   :-)

Comment: Well, I have no other idea than the settings differ. We can find out only by comparing the projects imo. Which is no big thing.

Comment: Works fine here too. Updated answer. No further idea, sorry.

Comment: no problem, I've given up, it was a simple investigation, I have no time to investigate further   :-)

Answer (score -1):

In your example you've named the single class in your module `F1` to the same name as the module, namely `F1`. Most likely Swift can't differentiate between module namespacing and the actual name of your class in the module, so when you just write `F1`, Swift possibly infers this to be an explicit namespacing annotation; refering to the namespace `F1` (made available by your import of module `F1`). A namespace can naturally not be treated as a type, which would explain the error message you're prompted with ([**emphasis mine**])

> Cannot call value of **non-function 'module...'**

You may test this theory by explicitly calling the class `F1`'s initializer of module `F1`, by including both the module namespace and its (single) class type in the call:

```
var c = F1.F1()
```

Comment: In that case the error changes to "Module 'F1' has no member named 'F1'"

Comment: Ah, then at least we are closer to the actual error. It seems like you haven't exposed any of the content of your module, which is possibly due to the fact that it isn't really a module (yet; you wrote however that you'd built the framework?), but just a Swift file. Have a look at [the following tutorial](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/how-to-create-a-pure-swift-module), particularly the step about _"generating `Logger.swiftdoc` and `Logger.swiftmodule`"_.

Comment: They are generated by the build process

Comment: @IanBell then I'm beat! I'll remove this answer shortly, perhaps you'd like to update your question about the error message you're prompted with when using explicit namespace typing (as I believe this is more relevant than the one you've posted in the current version of your question).

Comment: You can leave your reply here, maybe it can be useful for other people!

Comment: The Framework works fine here. You did not post the client project though. I assume there is the error. Check: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ggddhw40ykto2x/F2TestProjects.zip?dl=0 Open "F2TestWS.xcworkspace", choose schema F2TEST, build & run. Please update your question with all your information from the comments. If you can't make it, please also post the client project (project that imports F2.framework). We can delete the comments than so others can follow.